# Accordion: auto scroll to top of pane content

Tags: javascript, accordion

When using an accordion with big panes, selecting a pane will take you to its bottom content and leave the top content out off the screen's visibility. Forcing the user to scroll up each time when selecting a pane.

Is it possible to auto scroll to top of the pane content when selecting a pane?

Accordion available here: https://jsfiddle.net/4hqv4eao/4/

```
require([
    "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer",
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
    "dojo/ready"
  ],
  function(AccordionContainer, ContentPane, ready) {

    ready(function() {

      var acc = new AccordionContainer({}, "accordion");

      acc.addChild(new ContentPane({
        title: "Title 1",
      }, "pane1"));

      acc.addChild(new ContentPane({
        title: "Title 2",
      }, "pane2"));

      acc.addChild(new ContentPane({
        title: "Title 3",
      }, "pane3"));      

      acc.addChild(new ContentPane({
        title: "Title 4",
      }, "pane4"));        

      acc.startup();
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a click function for each pane (I used a `for loop` and the `className dijitAccordionInnerContainer`), you can get the accordions y position (I used the function from [here](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/get_element_position_using_javascript.htm) to get the exact y positon) and use `javascripts` [scrollBy method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy).

Here's the function to get the exact positon (thanks to kirupa):

```
// Helper function to get an element's exact position
function getPosition(el) {
  var xPos = 0;
  var yPos = 0;

  while (el) {
    if (el.tagName == "BODY") {
      // deal with browser quirks with body/window/document and page scroll
      var xScroll = el.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      var yScroll = el.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

      xPos += (el.offsetLeft - xScroll + el.clientLeft);
      yPos += (el.offsetTop - yScroll + el.clientTop);
    } else {
      // for all other non-BODY elements
      xPos += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
      yPos += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
    }

    el = el.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: xPos,
    y: yPos
  };
}
```

Here's the code I added to scroll to the top of the accordion:

```
var panes;
var pane;
panes = document.getElementsByClassName('dijitAccordionInnerContainer');

for (var i = 0; i < panes.length; i++) {
  panes[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    pane = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.scrollBy(0, getPosition(pane).y);
    }, 200);
  });
}
```

I used the `setTimeout` function so the accordion would be finished updating before getting it's position (there may be a better way for doing this).

Here's the [updated fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/4hqv4eao/6/).

Comment: The fix does not seem to be working when using the accordion with an iframe. More precisely it does not work if you provide a fix height to the iframe: [web page test](http://www.sensomarket.com/test/). It does work if you do not provide the fix height, but then again the iframe does not show the full content. Not sure where to go from here

Comment: It's getting the position of the pane based on the `iframe`, then scrolling the `window` of the `iframe`. Since you are setting a fixed `width` of the `iframe` it will not scroll the `iframe`.  In order for it to work in an `iframe` you'll need to get the position of the pane based on the parent of the iframe. To scroll the window, you'll need to do something like `window.parent.scrollBy` instead of `window.scrollBy`.

Comment: Hmm I replaced `window.scrollBy` with `window.parent.scrollBy` but doesn't seem to have any effect: [web page test2](http://www.sensomarket.com/test2/)  
`for (var i = 0; i < panes.length; i++) {  
  panes[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {  
    pane = this;  
    setTimeout(function() {  
      window.parent.scrollBy(0, getPosition(pane).y);  
    }, 200);  
  });  
}`